# Is there any restriction on no.of days of server logs stored when enabled on a s3 bucket?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-databricks

I have a bucket to which the server logs are enabled. And the server logs are stored in a destination path in any other s3 bucket.(not necessarily inside the same bucket) I have been analysing it from more than a month. And i observed that server logs are stored only for 33 days. After that the least date records are removed and new day's records are stored.

Ex: I have records from Feb 1. I have records stored without issues upto March 5. After that to store the records of March 6, records of Feb 1 are removed from storage and records of March 6 are stored.
Does anyone faced this issue? Did anyone analysed it? If no, I request anyone to do and let me know if you have observed the same.
Thanks!

Comment: That sounds like you have a lifecycle configuration on your logging bucket which removes old objects. Simply remove that config and you should be good to go.

Comment: Yes you are right. I didn't check that. Thanks!!